# Convolutional Neural Network with Logarithmic and Exponential activation functions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a very specific convolutional neural network using Keras.

The key difference is that I *have* to use non-usual activation functions: `log` and `exp`.
The basic structure of the ConvNet is as follows:

`Input => Conv2D => Activation Log => Avg Pooling => Activation Exp => ...`

The problem is: as the weights get too small, the `log` activation rapidly reaches `-inf`.

The reason why I need to use `log` and `exp` is because for certain layers I want to simulate what would be a *product pooling *, that is the product of a smaller window (filter) of the current layer.
If I apply `log(a)` and `log(b)`, I can do a normal *average pooling* `~ log(a)+log(b)` followed by an `exp` activation which corresponds to that product I want: `a * b = exp( log(a)+log(b) )`.

To get rid of the `-inf` I have tried to train the network with SGD and lower learning rate, so I could get larger weights, but it didn't work.

Please, do you have any idea on how could I avoid the `-inf` due to very small weights, or a smarter way of getting the *product pooling* without needing a `log` activation function?

Thank you.

Comment: what's the upper bound on the weights?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow. The reason I'm using ``log`` is just so I can get the product ``a*b`` of neurons *a* and *b* by summing ``log(a)+log(b)``. How would ``sinh`` help me with that? Thank you for your help. Preferably, the weights should be between 0 and 1, but no strict upper bound. Although they should be non-negative.

Comment: There is a reason why activation functions are bounded (`tanh`, `sigmoid`), or at least lower-bounded (`relu`)...

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the comment @desertnaut. I wish I didn't need to use ``log``, especially. But how could I perform the *product pooling*?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your activation output is rapidly reaching -inf tells me that the output of your convolution layer is quite small! I cannot provide you with a definite answer to how to avoid the -inf, for it depends on the structure of your network, the range of values of your input, and the task the network is trained to do.

However, I'd suggest two possible solutions:

1. You may need to reconsider your weight initialization technique. Many practical CNNs initialize from a Gaussian distribution with zero mean and relatively small variances, ~ 1x10^-3, and that will be an issue in you network because majority of weights are very small and will drive the convolution output below one.
2. Consider lower bounding your activation output, something like a max{..} function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Muhammad. Regarding your points: 1) I actually tried different initialization techniques. I have a constrain tho: must be non-negative. So, currently, I'm using ``RandomUniform(minval=0, maxval=1)``. I tried even silly things like bumping it up to ``minval=0.5``, but nothing worked. 2) I wish I could change the ``log`` to something else (with lower boundary) but I need it for the *product*-as-*sum* property (see the *product pooling* idea in my description).